# Kicad 6 can't find default library components - new install

Tags: kicad, linux

New to Kicad, have just installed via the new 6.0 release.

When I try and add a symbol, I get a "load error" pop-up with the following (heavily truncated):

```
Errors loading symbols:
Error loading symbol library 74xx.
Library file '${KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR}/74xx.lib' not found.
Error loading symbol library 4xxx_IEEE.
Library file '${KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR}/4xxx_IEEE.lib' not found.
Error loading symbol library 4xxx.
Library file '${KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR}/4xxx.lib' not found.
Error loading symbol library Amplifier_Audio.
Library file '${KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR}/Amplifier_Audio.lib' not found.
Error loading symbol library 74xGxx.
Library file '${KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR}/74xGxx.lib' not found.
Error loading symbol library Amplifier_Current.
Library file '${KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR}/Amplifier_Current.lib' not found.
Error loading symbol library Amplifier_Difference.
```

All the files are have been installed in the default directory - `/usr/share/kicad/library` and are there.

When I open an open source design, all the included components are present there, as in the design specific ones, but I have the same problem: I can't add to it.

I'm sure this is an easy fix, I just have no idea what that is.

Ubuntu 20.04
Kicad 6.0.0

[image: pop up]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue going from 5.9 to 6.0.
I used 'purge' command to remove 5.9, and installed 6.0
You have to remove the old config files / folders (KiCAD 5.9).

Step 1: In terminal, type: `dpkg --list`

Step 2: remove all these folders that have 5.9:

```
sudo apt-get remove kicad-doc-en
sudo apt-get remove kicad-footprints
sudo apt-get remove kicad-libraries
sudo apt-get remove kicad-packages3d
sudo apt-get remove kicad-symbols
sudo apt-get remove kicad-templates
```

Step 3: Do a new clean install. After the install, `dpkg --list` command should give you this:
[image]

Comment: Took some time off this one for a while, but your solution is the most comprehensive. 

For future readers, quickest way -

sudo apt-get remove kicad*

sudo rm -r -f ~/.config/kicad

sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:kicad/kicad-6.0-releases
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends kicad
# If you want demo projects
sudo apt install kicad-demos

Comment: `sudo rm -r -f ~/.config/kicad` actually `sudo` not required on that command. I only mention that because using `sudo` and `~` in the same command is a bit confusing. Also if you have multiple users you need to do this to all of their home directories.

Comment: Oof. Please do not delete other users' config files

Answer (score 6):

just to add to @Seth response... Ubuntu appears to be suffering from this a fair amount

https://forum.kicad.info/t/just-installed-v6-and-no-sysmbols-in-editor/32673/9

> We are currently unaware of any root cause of this happening on any
> platform, however we have had several Ubuntu users report that the
> default library tables (for example
> /usr/share/kicad/template/sym-lib-table) did not get updated to the
> 6.0 version when they updated the kicad package from 5.1 to 6.0. This results in the above problem, and can be fixed by completely
> uninstalling kicad (check that there is nothing left in
> /usr/share/kicad) and reinstalling it, and then removing the
> symbol/footprint library tables from your preferences folder
> (~/.config/kicad/6.0/) in order to get prompted to copy the global
> defaults again.

Comment: The part of the fix that fixes the problem is redoing the user config. Reinstalling the software does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have an old config file that was migrated.

You can remove `~/.config/kicad` and then rerun KiCad, accepting the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, removing .config/kicad have no effect, I get asked the config questions, I chose the default everywhere but no symbol is present.
${KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR} is not set

adding an environment variable KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR to /usr/share/kicad/library works for me (I'm on ubuntu)

I later found out KISYSMOD is also necessary so

```
export KICAD_SYMBOL_DIR=/usr/share/kicad/library
export KISYSMOD=/usr/share/kicad/modules
```

Comment: This isn't the correct way to fully migrate and only mitigates a partially migrated settings. By removing the settings directory as @Seth mentioned you should be fine. Ubuntu however appears to have a slight packaging issue so you might need to also do what Iwrote

Comment: I did what you say... Not working...

```sudo apt-get remove kicad; 
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/kicad/;
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt install --install-recommends kicad;
rm -rf ~/.config/kicad/6.0;
```

If I launch kicad I chose start with default settings, when I go to symbol editor, the copy default global is grayed...

Comment: seems like I had to reinstall kicad-footprints symbols libraries packages3d too

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, removing the config files from ~/.config/kicad/6.0/ was enough to get mine restored also. I accepted the defaults and the symbols were restored.

Answer (score 0):

Purging  my old KiCAD version and installing KiCAD 6 again helped when I had had the same issue  with the symbols library in Kicad_6.0.5 (Ubuntu 20.04LTS).

After this, I deleted the ~/.config/kicad file and starte KiCAD.

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the environment variables (*Preferences* > *Configure Paths...*) are set correctly. I previously had a nightly version installed and even after uninstalling the nightly packages, the environment variables were still set:

[image: paths]

Answer (score 0):

Just (re)add them manually. This was the only working solution for me:

1. Go to Preferences/Manage Symbol Libraries...
2. ...Global libraries
3. Click the Folder icon and browse to the system directory (defined in KICAD6_SYMBOL_DIR) /usr/share/kicad/symbols/
4. Select all (ctrl-a) all .kicad_sym files, apply

All Symbols are now enlisted in Global Library and my schema finds the symbols again.

Purge and reinstall nor removing .config/kicad did not resolve the issue for me.